# Using string value as a calculation in JS

Tags: javascript

I am storing a value in a DB (called generalparameter).

This value is a calculation which I call in the JS code.

The issue is the value is a string but I want it to be a calculation value.

e.g.
My DB value is:-

```
(((this.amount / new_rate) - this.stock_payment).toFixed(2) / (this.amount / new_rate) * 100).toFixed(2)
```

My code is:-

```
application.getGeneralParameter('UI','CAL_NEW_MARGIN');
```

But this yields:-

```
"(((this.amount / new_rate) - this.stock_payment).toFixed(2) / (this.amount / new_rate) * 100).toFixed(2)"
```

How do I get rid of the ""?

Thanks.

Ian.

Comment: Evil `eval` will help you

Comment: What database and what server language? You should be able to remove the quotes on the server.

Comment: Like other comments and answers said, eval() is your solution, but be carefull with `eval()` function, it's unsafe. And it is not good practice to store code like this in database, it's better if you store in db a flag or a identifier that calls the string in the code. It's only a recommendation. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

This works without the actual eval keyword - Function will however also evaluate so caution is advised if arbitrary strings can be saved in the DB since it will execute in the scope of the website your are on.

```js
var fnString = "(((this.amount / new_rate) - this.stock_payment).toFixed(2) / (this.amount / new_rate) * 100).toFixed(2)",
obj = {
  amount:3.9,
  stock_payment:42,
  calc : Function("var new_rate=6.9; return "+fnString)
}
alert(obj.calc())
```

Comment: Not sure whether `new Function` is much better than `eval` :-) It only works if `new_rate` is a global variable, for example.

Comment: @Bergi - moved new_rate to the function and added an advisory caution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `eval()` function, like so:

```
eval("(((this.amount / new_rate) - this.stock_payment).toFixed(2) / (this.amount / new_rate) * 100).toFixed(2)");
```

or like so:

```
eval(application.getGeneralParameter('UI','CAL_NEW_MARGIN'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. eval works, but might not be suitable due to injection issues etc, so I will proceed with care.